# Variable subsitution in tkinter

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

Why doesn't this code work

```
objects=[
    ('o','label', 0, 1),
    ('g','label', 0, 2),
    ('e','label', 0, 3),
    ('r','label', 1, 0),
    ('w','label', 2, 0),
    ('x','label', 3, 0),
]

for thing in objects:
    name = thing[0]
    type = thing[1]
    name = tk.type()
```

I am trying to use an list to define my tkinter widgets in an attempt to keep the code neat. The first item is the name and then the type. I keep getting this error.

```
module has no attribute type
```

I know what I'm doing wrong I just don't know how to fix it. How can I use the values that are stored in the variable to create the widget?

So I want `name = tk.type()` to be interpreted as `o = tk.label()`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you realize that you are assigning to `name` twice?  So `name = thing[0]` has no effect after you overwrite `name` by assign to `name` again.

Comment: I know. What I want to do is have `name = tk.type()` actually create a label named 'o' the value stored as name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work, because the second column in your list contains strings, not classes. Maybe you should store the actual class in  your objects list:

```
import Tkinter as tk
...
objects=[
    ('o',tk.Label, 0, 1),
    ('g',tk.Label, 0, 2),
    ('e',tk.Label, 0, 3),
    ('r',tk.Label, 1, 0),
    ('w',tk.Label, 2, 0),
    ('x',tk.Label, 3, 0),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr).

```
name = getattr(tk, type)
```

Now `name` is a function, so you can call it using function syntax (`name()`)

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter's label widget is spelled with a capital "L", so you need

```
objects=[
    ('o','Label', 0, 1),
    ('g','Label', 0, 2),
    ('e','Label', 0, 3),
    ('r','Label', 1, 0),
    ('w','Label', 2, 0),
    ('x','Label', 3, 0),
]
```